# How to protect, obfuscate or hide a .json service account in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm consuming an api (Speech to text) and I have a json file that I have to keep in the project. Is there any way similar to dart-define to protect this file?

Answer (score 1):

Putting a `.json` file in the assets can't be secured 100%, since the point of using it is to make it readable and understood by everyone, so trying to obfuscate it, like the `dart` obfuscating is not an option.

Sensitive data must be stored on android on the Keystore, and on iOS on the Keychain. There is a Flutter plugin that abstracts this for you (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage).

or  use some encrypting/decrypting tool, package, or using an `API` that will do it for you.